# Chrome / Firefox Cached Images Issue

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I'm having trouble when preloading images and creating elements on the fly. The script loads a list of image URLs, creates canvas elements etc.

The problem is that on subsequent "soft" refreshes or submission of the same URL the preload loop isn't initiated, so the canvas elements etc. are not created. I'm pretty certain this has something to do with resource caching - however - why the script isn't iterating through the image URL list and building the DOM as expected I'm not sure... [Here's an example](http://encycolorpedia.com/color-palette-generator?URL=http://bit.ly/159sN71&limit=16&colorspace=CIELab)

The JavaScript on the page is optimised output, but the preload loop looks like this:

```
// Images array
var images = [];

for (var i = 0; i < l.length; ++i) {
    // Create canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    // Canvas element properties
    canvas.width = l[i].w;
    canvas.height = l[i].h;
    canvas.style.display = 'none';
    // Image element + mouse over event
    images[i] = document.getElementById('i' + i).getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    images[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        handleCanvas(this);
    }, false);
    // Push canvas into DOM
    images[i].parentNode.insertBefore(canvas, images[i]);
    // Preload item from processed images list
    var image = new Image;
    image.src = l[i].i;
}
```

I'd prefer not to resort to headers or "URL?random=37436464" type fixes if possible. Tested on nightly versions of Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation (testing in IE9) it appears the issue was cause by asynchronous loading of the JavaScript and lagging variable initiation.